# Closure Compiler use_types_for_optimization doing nothing

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Setting `use_types_for_optimization` to true has little or no effect on this code of mine. The output files are identical or the same size with different property names in a few places. No matter what I do, all property names are unique across all objects.

I have two examples of this, but it would be a lot of code to lay it out. One example is an ES6 `class`, and the other is a global Object.  I have used `@typedef` and `@type`.  I have tried using `@interface` and `@record`.  Nothing makes any difference.

Here are some examples of the basic syntax I tried:

```
class myClass {
  constructor () {
    /** type {boolean} */
    this.prop = true;
  }
}

/** @typedef {{prop:(boolean)}} */
let myObj = {prop:true};
```

What must I do to get Closure Compiler to make the properties within a type unique only within that type? It seems like it should be straightforward, but I have yet to figure it out.

Comment: Do you have `@param` & `@return` annotations everywhere?

Comment: I do not have `@param` or `@return` anywhere.  I am not using Closure Library, and this is my first set of JSDoc tags.

Comment: It's difficult to respond well without more context.  The type-based optimizations are pretty subtle, so without seeing how you're _using_ these things, it's not clear why the compiler would or would not (dis)ambiguate them.  In particular, though, the compiler does not make any guarantees about properties it considers different: i.e. it may very likely name them both 'a' even if it knows they're completely separate - what it tries very hard _not_ to do is to name the _same_ property two _different_ things.  Also, `@param` and `@return` are necessary for optimization, not just Closure Library.

Answer (score 0):

If properties are being renamed, then `use_types_for_optimization` is doing what it was intended for. Without it, any property with the same name as a property in an extern file cannot be renamed.

If two properties on different objects are known to have no relationship to each other, the compiler will try to rename them to the same name. This results in a smaller gzip output.

If you are trying to rename properties but ensure that each type has a unique property name, you would need to make a custom build of the compiler. In particular, you would need to disable the "AmbiguateProperties" pass.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have also received a response on the CC mailing list, and it included an example.  See [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/closure-compiler-discuss/NjM-NgH53cg/iCm3UbtWAAAJ).